# .htaccess redirects /robots.txt to /robots.txt/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have the following in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ /$1$2/ [R=302,L]
```

This line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` does not exclude txt files. How can I also exclude txt files from the following `RewriteRule`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude .txt files using the following condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.txt$
```